# How I can enable ads model on shopify store?

Tags: shopify, ads, shopify-api

Actually, I am trying to find a way to add ads on my Shopify store. Ads will come from sellers or other entities paid directly for me, so I am the only one who will control which ads will be posted in my website.

So, I am trying to find a way to enable Ads Model on my website, Ads model will help me to add automation ads for specific seller and set duration and place of ads, etc.

So, Maybe my home page contains ad banners & normal banners.
Any idea if we are able to integrate Shopify store with the ads model, or any info that help me to do that?

Comment: What approaches did you consider already? And what‘s your problem exactly?

Comment: if you are a seller on my website and you want to add a banner as ads on my website, i need to do that manually, i am searching away to have a dashboard allow me to add ads automatically like google adscence, but google adscense will not working fine because i need to only add ads for me seller?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to programming at all. At most it's a recommendation question, which are off-topic here.